# Space on right side of website

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have an odd space I can't seem to get rid of on my site. I have spend the last few days messing with the css to try and make the #menubar cover 100% width as it is suppose to but can't work it out.

It becomes much more prominent when accessing the site via a smartphone. I am using flex slider jquery plugin for the images, but have changed it on my clients request to re size based on height rather than width.

site is http://www.testsite.co.nz/

Comment: Please provide a [reduced test case](http://css-tricks.com/reduced-test-cases/) and include a demo on Jsfiddle or Codepen so we can help you better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a CSS-rule:

```
body > div {
    padding: 2px;
}
```

And your header `<div>` has `width:100%`. So it is 4px wider than the viewport.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure `html` and `body` are set to `width: 100%`.

Answer (score 1):

You probably have a margin on something (some things like the body have margins by default).

The easiest way is to open your site in Google Chrome and inspect element, this will show you the margins.

Answer (score 0):

I have changed

```
<div id="logo" onclick="location.href='http://www.sgphotostudio.co.nz';" style="cursor: pointer;"></div>
```

to

```
<img src="../img/SGlogo.png" onclick="location.href='http://www.sgphotostudio.co.nz';" class="main_logo">
```

and added styles below

```
#menubar img.main_logo {
    border: medium none;
    cursor: pointer;
    float: left;
    height: 76px;
    margin: 6px 0 0 200px;
}
#menu {
    float: left;
    list-style: none outside none;
    margin-top: 34px;
    width: auto;
    z-index: 10;
}
```